# Chrome Remote Debugging Console Not Working on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, adb

I've suddenly started having this problem when remote debugging a Zebra MC40 Android handheld scanner for a customer. I used Chrome thoroughly in the past to develop on this platform, and suddenly the console doesn't work, nor does the F5/refresh command. The console just shows a newline every time I press Enter. Last time I successfully used it was in January. Everything else I've tried works - source display, breakpoints, even the remote screen display. I've tried on 2 PCs with the latest version of ADB. The scanner is running Android 4.4.4.

Has anyone seen this, or does anyone have any ideas what to try next?

Thanks.

Comment: Try an older version of Chrome portable - the new Chrome might have stopped supporting the old Android.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be it. Using Chrome Portable 70.0.3538.110 still works. Didn't know about Chrome Portable which makes using an older version a much more reasonable solution. Surprised I didn't see a release note about this since it seems like a pretty big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 72 and greater seems to break debugging with Android 4.4.4. Using Chrome Portable 70 seems to solve the problem. Thanks to wOxxOm for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers, I downloaded an older version of chromium, 70.0.3538.124, which is the most recent version of 70 I believe.  Dev tools for Android 4.4 worked properly for me with this version.

Windows x64:

- https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/587811/

Linux x64:

- https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/587811/

Other:

- https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html
- Select your OS
- Filter by 587811

You can follow the directions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1361373/951213) to download other versions.

I believe 71.0.3578.141 is the newest version of 71 if you wanted to try that. You can find other exact version numbers by ctrl+f'ing [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+refs).